# Independence of zeros of polynomials modulo $p$

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, congruences

Under which (nice) hypotheses on two polynomials $f, g \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ can we say that there exists a prime number $p$ such that $p$ divides $f(n)$ for some positive integer $n$, and $p$ does not divide $g(m)$ for all positive integers $m$ ?

It is easy to find necessary conditions, for example $g$ cannot be a power of $f$. However I am stuck in finding a (non-trivial) sufficient condition.

Thanks.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question but it seems like you just need to look at the reductions of $f$ and $g$ mod $p$; $f$ should be equivalent to the zero polynomial and $g$ should have no roots

Comment: @ThomasGrubb No, the question is about $f$ having a zero modulo $p$, not being identically zero modulo $p$. Anyway, how do you know if there exists a prime $p$ such that $f$ has a zero modulo $p$ and $g$ has no zero modulo $p$ ?

Comment: @sercej I see; I misread the question originally. I suspect this might be hard, especially since there are polynomials such as $g(x)=x^4-10x^2+1$ which are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ but are reducible mod $p$ for all $p$.